# Unable to solve for a series involving ap and gp.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Second, forth and eighth terms of an AP series are the first three terms of a GP series.

I am asked to find the common ratio.

For the AP series I reached the following expressions however I was unable to find a common ratio.

$a+ d, a+ 3d, a+ 7d$.

Comment: I still require assistance

Comment: Now, since, $a+ d, a+ 3d, a+ 7d$, belong to GP, therefore, $(a+3d)^2=(a+d)(a+7d)$. Upon solving you get, $d=0,\frac a2$. Can you now see which value of $d$ is valid and consequently what the common ratio will be?

Comment: @Anonymous_original. Are you sure about $\frac a 2$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah sorry it should have been $d$.

Comment: In reference to my initial comment, both values of $d$ are valid.

Answer (score 0):

There are two expressions for the common ratio.  If set them equal, we have
$$\frac{a+3d}{a+d} = \frac{a+7d}{a+3d}.$$
Cross multiply to get $a^2+6ad+9d^2=a^2+8ad+7d^2$.  Cancel some stuff to get $2d^2=2ad$ and conclude that $a=d$.  Therefore the 2nd, 4th, and 8th terms are $2a, 4a$, and $8a$.  If $a$ is not zero, then the common ration is 2.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 term of the geometric sequence are $k=a+d, kx=a+3d,$ and $kx^2=a+7d$ for some $k,d.$ Hence $(a+3d)^2=(kx^2)^2=k(kx^3)=(a+d)(a+7d).$ The equation $(a+3d)^2=(a+d)(a+7d)$ simplifies to $2d(d-a)=0.$

One solution to this is $d=0,$ which makes both sequences into constant sequences, with constant value $a.$ Constant sequences ARE  arithmetic and geometric sequences. If $a\ne 0=d$ then the ratio $x$ of successive terms of the geometric sequence is $1.$ If $a=d=0$ the common ratio $x$ is undefinable, as all the information we have is $0=k=kx=kx^2=kx^3=...$

The other solution to the equation $2d(d-a)=0$ is $a=d$ which makes  the first 3 terms of the geometric sequence  $2a,4a,8a.$ Again, if $a=0$ then the common ratio $x$ is undefinable. If $d=a\ne 0$ the common ratio $x$ is $4a/2a=2.$